# SQL Server: Alert when updating large no. of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Today I f*ed up the most important table on my company's website. I forgot to add the where clause after an update statement and the login for all the users were changed. About 13,000 to be aprrox.

Is there a way in SQL Server or SQL Server Management Studio to give an alert if an update or delete is made for say, more than 10 rows?

Comment: I don't think you need it.  You only make that mistake once, and after your heart has dropped through your feet, running even a select statement on the live server will give you the sweats.

Comment: Always do stuff like that within a transaction, so you can roll back just in case...

Comment: In addition to running updates within a transaction, I would suggest you religiously take the select statements that contain the data you want to update, and turn that statement into an update statement (complete with where clause, of course). @devrooms comment is also accurate in my experience. Hope you had a backup...

Comment: @devrooms
Actually this was the 2nd time something like this happened.
I had to do quite a lot of updates. So I was typing really fast and executing them one by one. Luckily I had a backup. Thanks for the suggestions guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly different approach, but if you want to be alerted to the fact that you're using a production server, [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) (a free add-in for SSMS) has a nifty feature called *Window Connection Colouring*.

You associate each SQL Server you use with a colour, and each query window has a corresponding coloured bar at the top.  All my production servers are red; dev are green; and test/staging are orange. It's always quite apparent to me when I need to be careful.

Also, by default, every new query window opens with a `BEGIN TRAN` / `ROLLBACK` statement so you remember to test potentially damaging queries first.

Note I have no commercial interest in the software, but I have found it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an on update trigger that fails when the inserted table has above X number of rows, though then later if you really did want to make the change you'll need to disable/renable the trigger (not hard, but annoying - which is what you're after, I suppose).

But yes, if you're doing things manually they should be in a begin tran / rollback transaction with a select at the end to verify what you were doing, and only after you're happy with it then commit it. (We can probably all tell you of at least one case where we thought we were happy with it and still committed it incorrectly, though - haha).